# How to start and run a virtualenv in python script?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a virtual environment, start it, and then have every command after that be executed in the virtual environment.

```
    1. os.system("curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py")
    2. os.system("python3 get-pip.py")
    3. os.system("mkdir Apps")
    4. os.system("pip3 install virtualenv")
    5. os.system("virtualenv virt")
    6. os.system("source virt/bin/activate")
    7. os.system("pip3 install flask")
```

This is the code I have right now and I am trying to create the virtual environment on line (5) and then trying to activate it on line (6) and then do the 7th line (install flask) on the virtual environment.

I also have tried `os.system('. virt/bin/activate')` but every-time I run the python file it goes through and it does everything except start the virtual environment.

I am running this on the terminal on Mac.

Comment: python3 comes with `pip` and `venv`... You can `import` them rather than using `os.system`

Comment: I'd suggest using `Pipenv`, or just Docker if you are trying to make this as portable code

Comment: This is the kind of thing a shell script is very good at setting up for you.

Comment: In addition: [Things to consider when you are using `pip` inside a python script](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program).

Comment: Each `os.system()` call creates a separate shell instance whose context (such as, the effects of any `source` command) will be lost when that instance exits and `os.system()` returns control to your Python script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate+subprocess

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the virtual environment is only active for the duration of the `os.system()` call. In many cases there is no need to activate the virtual environment, just find its `bin` directory and run the binaries found in it.

Something of the sort:

- `os.system('/path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip install flask')`
- `os.system('/path/to/venv/bin/pip install flask')`

For a different approach:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pathlib
import subprocess
import venv

class _EnvBuilder(venv.EnvBuilder):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.context = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def post_setup(self, context):
        self.context = context

def _venv_create(venv_path):
    venv_builder = _EnvBuilder(with_pip=True)
    venv_builder.create(venv_path)
    return venv_builder.context

def _run_python_in_venv(venv_context, command):
    command = [venv_context.env_exe] + command
    print(command)
    return subprocess.check_call(command)

def _run_bin_in_venv(venv_context, command):
    command[0] = str(pathlib.Path(venv_context.bin_path).joinpath(command[0]))
    print(command)
    return subprocess.check_call(command)

def _main():
    venv_path = pathlib.Path.cwd().joinpath('virt')
    venv_context = _venv_create(venv_path)
    _run_python_in_venv(venv_context, ['-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', 'pip'])
    _run_bin_in_venv(venv_context, ['pip', 'install', 'attrs'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

Comment: @NathanBelete Does that answer your question?

Comment: I wanted to run a python script on a specific virtual environment, and this answer helps such that I ran "path-to-venv_python/python main.py" on a terminal.